# Get random key:value pairs from dictionary in python

Tags: python, csv, random, dictionary

I'm trying to pull out a random set of key-value pairs from a dictionary I made from a csv file. The dictionary contains information for genes, with the gene name being the dictionary key, and a list of numbers (related to gene expression etc.) being the value.

```
# python 2.7.5
import csv
import random

genes_csv = csv.reader(open('genes.csv', 'rb'))

genes_dict = {}
for row in genes_csv:
    genes_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]

length = raw_input('How many genes do you want? ')

for key in genes_dict:
    random_list = random.sample(genes_dict.items(), int(length))
    print random_list
```

The problem is, if I try to get a list of 100 genes (for example), it seems to iterate over the whole dictionary and return every possible combination of 100 genes.

Comment: That's precisely what you're doing with `for key in genes_dict`. Remove that line and you're good to go!

Comment: You sure you need that `for key in genes_dict: ...`? It will iterate over every key of the dictionary. That's probably why you get the impression that it gives you every possible combination of 100 genes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to get random `K` elements from dictionary `D` you simply use

```
import random
random.sample( D.items(), K )
```

and that's all you need.

From the Python's documentation:

> random.**sample**(*population*, *k*)
>
> Return a *k* length list of unique elements
>   chosen from the *population* sequence. Used for random sampling without
>   replacement.

In your case

```
import csv
import random

genes_csv = csv.reader(open('genes.csv', 'rb'))

genes_dict = {}
for row in genes_csv:
    genes_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]

length = raw_input('How many genes do you want? ')
random_list = random.sample( genes_dict.items(), int(length) )
print random_list
```

There is no need to iterate through all the keys of the dictionary

```
for key in genes_dict:
    random_list = random.sample(genes_dict.items(), int(length))
    print random_list
```

notice, that you are actualy not using the `key` variable inside your loop, which should warn you that something may be wrong here.  Although it is **not true** that it " return every possible combination of 100 genes.", it simply returns `N` random `k` element genes lists (in your case 100), where `N` is the size of the dictionary, which is far from being "all combinations" (which is `N!/(N-k)!k!`)

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in genes_dict:
    random_list = random.sample(genes_dict.items(), int(length))
    print random_list
```

Goes through every key, and for each key prints a sample. You're looking for just

```
random_list = random.sample(genes_dict.items(), int(length))
print random_list
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the others no iteration needed with the dictionary keys. However if you do not want the format returned as a tuple but as a list you can use

```
 random_list=genes_dict.keys() int(length)
```

Then for getting the values you a loop if the "int(length)" is more than one:

```
 for x in random_list:
       print x,genes_dict[x]
       //or to create a new dict of the random values you could
       random_genes_dict[x]=genes_dict[x]
```