# Randomly select a subset of lines in a fasta file

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file of around 18 million reads. I brought the head of it into Python and built built a dictionary where the key = readID and value = sequence using a forloop w/ if/else statements.

I would like to now randomly select a subset of 10,000 reads from my original file . I think another for loop is necessary, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a fasta or a fastq file? Can you show some sample data and the code you already developed?

Answer (score 3):

When you're working with FASTQfiles, then you should really be using [BioPython](https://biopython.org/). It has support for reading FASTQ files and turning them into a dictionary, no for-loop needed. [For taking random samples, use the `random` module from the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955554/get-random-keyvalue-pairs-from-dictionary-in-python).

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
import random

record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("example.fastq", "fastq"))
random_reads = random.sample(record_dict.items(), 10000)
for readID, sequence in random_reads:
    print(readID, sequence)
```